# Declaritively hide a task list's timeline

Tags: sharepoint-online, xslt-list-view-web-part, view

I am trying to hide a task list's timeline declaritively, either in the View or XSLTListViewWebPart. The XLSTListViewWebPart is being added via a module and file, like so:

```
<File Url="default.aspx" Path="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" >
        <Property Name="Title" Value="Open Issues" />
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="ProjectDashboardContentType" />
        <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/ProjectPortal-OpenIssues.aspx" />
        <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811009A4931CEF4F842B9BDFAF179837C58E2" />
        <View WebPartZoneID="ProjectPortalZone" WebPartOrder="0" List="Lists/ProjectTasks" DefaultView="FALSE" BaseViewID="6">
                        <![CDATA[
            <webParts>
             <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                <metaData>
                 <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                 <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                </metaData>
                <data>
                 <properties>
                    <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                    <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
                    <property name="Title" type="string">Project Tasks</property>
                 </properties>
                </data>
             </webPart>
            </webParts>
         ]]>
    </View>


    </File>
```

Is there a property that can be added to remove the timeline here? Or perhaps it's something that has to be set in the view that is referenced by BaseViewId="6"?

*** EDIT ***

I suppose I could just output some CSS or do some clever jQuery that'll hide that entire area, but would rather remove it from rendering altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was able to do this by removing the *TimelineDueDate* column from the View definition in my list schema:

```
<View BaseViewID="2" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Late_Tasks;" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="False" Url="late.aspx" ReqAuth="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issuelst.png?rev=23">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Checkmark"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="StartDate" /><FieldRef Name="DueDate"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="Status" /><FieldRef Name="pdTaskType" /></ViewFields>
    <ViewData>
      <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="StrikeThroughPercentComplete"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate"></FieldRef>
    </ViewData> 
...
```

Just remove the DueDate FieldRef from ViewData, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you add your webpart using xml (like in the .webpart files) you can add the following property

```
<property name="ShowTimelineIfAvailable" type="bool">False</property>
```